# Disable the button action if the user refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hello and sorry for the confusing title, I will explain it shortly :

I got a button with a cooldown in "turns" (Website RPG) :

```
  if (isset($_POST['fdd_attackbas3'])) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['last_post'])) {
      $_SESSION['last_post'] = 0;
    }

    $currtime = time();
    if ($currtime  > ($_SESSION['last_post'] + 0.5)) {
      $_SESSION['last_post'] = $currtime;

      // Do things and reduce cooldown
    }
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.5" />';
  }
}
```

So basically, if the cooldown of this button is 3, the user won't be able to click it until 3 turns. A turn can be an attack, using item...

The problem is that if the user press f5 or refresh the page after using the button, he will be able to attack twice, setting the cooldown to 6, and 9 after he refresh 2 times, 12 after 3 times and so on.

The button automatically reload after using it to display to the user the damages done, so i need to be careful with the unload script.

Thanks for the help !

**EDIT  : I resolved the problem by doing this :**

if (isset($_POST['fdd_attackultime']) AND ($infomonstre["fightm_cdultime"] < 1)) {

Explaination : I added a condition "Cooldown < 1" so the user won't be able to attack by refreshing as the cooldown is not < 1.

Comment: Look at [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Maybe you could store the "cooldown" value. And, if exist on load, use it.